# Using javascript and Moment.js. Gotta show only this week, monday - sunday

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, handlebars.js, momentjs

I'm having some troubles with Javascript. I'm not that advanced when it comes to programming in Javascript, so I'm having  a tough time.

What I gotta do is making a calendar from scratch, the problem I have right now, is having my code to only display THIS WEEK, and only this week. then when pressed on the right arrow, it should display the next week, or when pressed on the left arrow, it should display the next before.

Everything is made local.

Everything on the site itself, is in Danish, but I've commented in english, and named the variables in english, so dont worry about all the output text.

here's some code

**!! UPDATE !!** 
JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/b6n3d36a/
the days wont display at all, please help

** !! UPDATE 2 !!*
I fixed it. I got help from a co-worker. We got it working.
Thanks to everyone looking into this.

**THE INDEX FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0" />
    <title>Nikolaj kalender</title>
    <script src="js/libs/handlebars/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/moment/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/core.js"></script>

    <!-- RESPONSIVE STYLESHEET -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/responsive/responsive.css">
    <!-- STANDARD STYLE SHEET -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {



        moment.locale('da');   //danish language
        startdate = moment("2016-06-07");  //todays date (yy-mm-dd-h:i:s) not sure if right format thought
        var new_date = moment(startdate, "DD").add(5, 'days');

        var day = new_date.format('ddd');
        // var month = new_date.format('MM');
        // var year = new_date.format('YYYY');

        var dataSet = {
            dates: []
        }


        var today = moment();
        var todayDay = today.format('ddd'); // get TODAY date (ex; 2nd)


        function generateDaterange() {
            var start = new Date();

            var dates = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                var d = new Date(start.getTime());
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + i);
                console.log(d);
                var date = {
                    date: d,
                    date_human: moment(d).format('ddd'),
                    date_humanDays: moment(d).format('Do')
                    //date_human_today: moment(d).text("hello")
                }


                dates.push(date);
            }
            console.log(dates);
            console.log("heroppe ovenover")
            dataSet.dates = dates;

        }


//    var dataSetToday = dataSet[0];               //todays date in our array
//    var val_to_replace = ",";                    //this is what has to be replaced
//    var replace_with = "--";                     //this is what shall be there instead
//            $.each(dataSetToday, function(key, val){
//                dataSetToday[key] = val.replace(val_to_replace, replace_with);
//          }
//        console.log(dataSetToday);


        function init() {
            generateDaterange();
            buildDaterange();
        }


        init();

        function buildDaterange() {

            console.log('build')

            $.each(dataSet.dates, function (k, v) {

                var title =  String(v.date_human).substr(0, 1);

                if(dateIsToday(new Date(), v.date))
                    title = 'I DAG';


                $('.cal_header thead th').eq(k).text(title)
                $('.cal_header tbody td p').eq(k).text(v.date_humanDays)


            })

        }
        var startweek = moment().startOf('isoWeek');
        var endweek = moment().endOf('isoWeek');

        console.log("herunder er slut for ugen");
        console.log(endweek);

        function dateIsToday(date_a, date_b){

            return (
                    date_a.getDate() == date_b.getDate() &&
                    date_a.getMonth() == date_b.getMonth() &&
                    date_a.getFullYear() == date_b.getFullYear()

            )
        }

        function thisWeek(date_c, date_d){

        }


    });


</script>
<div class="create_form">

</div>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header_for_cal">
        <div id="back_btn"><p><span> < </span>Tilbage</p></div>
        <div id="cal_header_title"><h3>Kalender</h3></div>
        <div><p>+</p></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="contentForDate">
        <div class="dateHeader">
            <img src="images/content/header.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="date_content">
            <div>
                <h3>Svømmehal</h3>
                <p>Aarup Svømmehal</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Tirsdag, 13 Juni, 2016</p>
                <p>10:00 - 12:00</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    ge Lorem Ipsum er, at teksten indeholder mere
                    eller mindre almindelig tekstopbygning
                    i modsætning til "Tekst her – og mere tekst her", mens det samtidigt ligner almindelig tekst.
                    Mange layoutprogrammer og we
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="cal_header">
    <div id="left_arrow">
        <p> < </p>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p></p></td>
                <td><p></p></td>
                <td><p></p></td>
                <td><p></p></td>
                <td><p></p></td>
                <td><p></p></td>
                <td><p></p></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="right_arrow">
        <p> > </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="activities">
    <ul id="swimming">
        <li class="activi_time">KL 09:00</li>
        <li class="activi_title">Svømmehal
            <p class="title_sub">Aarup Svømmehal</p></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="activi_time">KL 10:00<p class="time_sub">KL 10:30</p></li>
        <li class="activi_title">Vaske tøj</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="activi_time">KL 13:00</li>
        <li class="activi_title">Lav Té</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="activi_time">KL 22:00</li>
        <li class="activi_title">Godnat</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="images/icons/calendar.png">
            <p>Kalendar</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/icons/walkthrough.png">
            <p>Gennemgange</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/icons/food.png">
            <p>Mad</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/icons/activities.png">
            <p>Aktiviteter</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/icons/more.png">
            <p>Mere</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**HERE'S THE CSS**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
body{
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
#wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:100%;
}
.contentForDate{
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    right:-100%;
    z-index:9999;
}
.date_content{
    padding:0px 10px;
}
.contentForDate .dateHeader img{
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}

.contentForDate div{
    max-width:100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.contentForcccDate div:nth-of-type(2){
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.contentForDate div:nth-of-type(2) p{
    max-width:100%;
    color:grey;
    font-size:14px;
}
.contentForDate div:nth-of-type(3) p{
    color:grey;
    margin-top:7px;
    max-width:90%;
}
.cal_header{
    width:100%;
    min-height: 10px;
    background-color: #efeff4;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.activities ul{
    background-color:white;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:2px solid lightgrey;
    z-index:8;
}
.activities ul li{
display:inline-block;
    font-size:15px;
    position:relative;
}
.activities ul li:first-of-type{
    margin-left:35px;
    padding:10px 10px 25px 0px;
    border-right:2px solid #0273b2;
    z-index:99;
}
.activities ul li p{
font-size:12px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
}

.timerange li{
    display:block ;
    float:left;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border:none;

}
/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {

}
th {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    padding:12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:lighter;
}
tbody tr{
    border-top:1px solid grey;
}
td{
    width:20px;
}
td {
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size:14px;
}
td.currentDay{
    color:gray;
}
td p{
    padding:7px;
    width:20px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
p#selectedDate{
    background-color: #0273b2;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.calendar{
    width: 100%;
}

#left_arrow, #right_arrow{
    width:40px;
    background-color:darkgrey;
    position:relative;
}
#left_arrow p, #right_arrow p{
    position:absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 40%;
    color:white;
    font-weight:lighter;
}

#header_for_cal{
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#0273b2;
    color:white;
    font-weight:lighter;
    padding:20px 0;
    z-index:99999;
}
#header_for_cal h3{
    font-weight:lighter;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:21px;
}
#cal_header_title{
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#cal_header_title {
    text-align:right;
}

#header_for_cal div:nth-of-type(2){
    flex-grow:1;
}

#header_for_cal div:nth-of-type(3){
    flex-grow: 1;
}
#header_for_cal div:nth-of-type(3) p{
    float:right;
}

#header_for_cal p{
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:lighter;
    font-size:17px;
}

#swimming{
    cursor:pointer;
}

#footer{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:white;
    border-top:2px solid grey;
}

#footer ul{
    text-align:center;
}
#footer ul li{
    display: inline-block;

    padding:7px 10px;
    margin:0px 4px;
    color:#0273b2;
}
#footer ul li img{
    max-width:35px;
}
```

**HERE'S THE JQUERY CODE FOR SOME ANIMATED STUFF (NOT THAT IMPORTANT AT THIS MOMENT)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".contentForDate").hide();

$(".cal_header p").click(function(e){

    $('.cal_header p#selectedDate').removeAttr('id');

    if($(e.target).is('.cal_header td p')){
        $(this).attr('id', 'selectedDate');

    }

    });

    $("#back_btn").hide();
    $("#swimming").click(function(){


        if ( $(".contentForDate" ).is( ":hidden")) {
            $(".contentForDate").show(200);
            var left = $('.contentForDate').offset().left;

            $(".contentForDate").css({left:left}).animate({"left":"0%"}, "fast");
                 $("#back_btn").show();
        }
    });

    $("#back_btn").click(function(){

        if($(".contentForDate").css("display", "block")){
            $(".contentForDate" ).hide(200);
            $("#back_btn").hide();
        }


    });

});
```

Hope you can help me, I've ran out of ideas to what to do, and I've tried searching for it on here, but nothing seems to work. So here goes nothing :)

Comment: Attaching a https://jsfiddle.net/ would be nice.

Comment: About to post the link, just gonna make sure everything is working :)

Comment: yeah you should add a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) snippet.

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/b6n3d36a/
I'm also having trouble displaying the days+date now, when I integrated it all into jsfiddle..

Comment: I've made an updated version, with some other external sources. not that it helped tho, but less resources is better than a ton

https://jsfiddle.net/b6n3d36a/3/

Comment: Do you absolutely have to make this yourself? There are various javascript calendar plugins around which are very flexible and would probably do what you need. The best one I've found is FullCalendar (http://www.fullcalendar.io)

Comment: I've been told to do this from scratch. I could try to talk to my superiors and ask if its not okay if I use some kind of plugins, and just style it, they way they want it to be styled. But even so,I just fixed it.